# Must include AWSEBDockerrunVersion key in the Dockerrun.aws.json file

Tags: node.js, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker

Trying to move my Docker Compose application to Elastic Beanstalk and having some issues.

Been struggling with this for like a week now, come pretty far but still some big issues. I converted my `docker-compose.yml` to a `Dockerrun.aws.json` using [container transform](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform):

```json
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "entryPoint": [
        "/client/entrypoint.sh"
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 512,
      "image": "nodejs",
      "links": [
        "server_dans_backend:server_dans_backend"
      ],
      "name": "client_dans_backend",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3000,
          "hostPort": 3000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
          "value": "ABC"
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
          "value": "ABC"
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
          "value": "ABC"
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_HOST",
          "value": "ABC"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "image": "postgres:14-alpine",
      "memory": 512,
      "name": "db_dans_backend",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 5432,
          "hostPort": 5432
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "essential": true,
      "image": "nginx:alpine",
      "memory": 512,
      "links": [
        "server_dans_backend",
        "client_dans_backend"
      ],
      "name": "nginx_dans_backend",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 80
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "entryPoint": [
        "/app/server/entrypoint.sh"
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "image": "alpine:python",
      "memory": 512,
      "links": [
        "db_dans_backend:db_dans_backend"
      ],
      "name": "server_dans_backend",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 8000,
          "hostPort": 8000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Pretty straightforward - Node (NextJS), Python (Django), Nginx and Postgres

My problem is this, it doesn't work in prod and whenever I try `eb local run` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: ValidationError - The AWSEBDockerrunVersion key in the Dockerrun.aws.json file is not valid or is not included.
```

Even weirder, when I actually `eb deploy` I get this:

```
Instance deployment: 'Dockerrun.aws.json' in your source bundle specifies an unsupported version. Elastic Beanstalk only supports version 1 for non compose app and version 3 for compose app. The deployment failed.
```

But there is no version 3 for this file format.

I'm not particularly sure why this is a problem though since the key is clearly included. I read it could be a problem if your EB platform isn't multidocker but I believe my platform is correct.

When I run `eb platform show` I get the following:

```
64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.16 running Docker
```

which I believe is valid - the only other option would be the ECS+EB option which I don't believe works with `eb local run` anyway.

Thank you in advance, been really struggling with this.

Comment: The Docker Amazon Linux 2 platform uses the Dockerrun.aws.json v3 file for environments that use Docker Compose. It uses the Dockerrun.aws.json v1 file for environments that don't use Docker Compose. [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html)

Comment: @Jarad thankyou for the response! I've tried using 3 instead and get the exact same error - any advice?

Comment: One thought is, I've had experience with `eb deploy` not working due to bugs. Maybe try uploading the zipped bundle file directly just to see if it works then and if not, what the error is.

Comment: @Jarad I think you may be right - it seems to uploading correctly when I do "3" as a string. Seems there are other bugs but at least it's uploading now! Thank you!